# Modify a struct within a List

Tags: c#, arraylist, struct

Working with

```cs
private struct Emitter 
{
    public string COM;
    public string FW_Version;
    public string DAE_Version;
};
private List<int> EmitterToBootload;
private int EmitterToBootloadIndex;
private List<Emitter> Emitters;
```

I get 
"Cannot modify the return value of 'List<namespace.Emitter>.this[int]' because it is not a variable"

For this code

```cs
Emitters[EmitterToBootload[EmitterToBootloadIndex]].FW_Version = fw;
```

I tried this workaround, is it correct ?

```cs
Emitter em = Emitters[EmitterToBootload[EmitterToBootloadIndex]];
em.FW_Version = fw;
Emitters[EmitterToBootload[EmitterToBootloadIndex]] = em;
```

Can someone explain to me what's wrong with my first code ?

Comment: If you have do use structs, your workaround is the solution, otherwise as Olivier explained, use a class instead. Also mutable struct should be avoided (to avoid issues like yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the struct is a value type and not a reference type, the list indexer returns a copy of the struct and not a reference to the struct in the list.

If you could modify this struct, it would only affect your local copy and the struct in the list would remain unchanged.

Note that this is different for arrays because indexing an array yields the very position inside the array.

The list indexer is [implemented like this](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L174):

```cs
public T this[int index] {
    get {
        // Following trick can reduce the range check by one
        if ((uint) index >= (uint)_size) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        return _items[index]; 
    }

    set {
        if ((uint) index >= (uint)_size) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        _items[index] = value;
        _version++;
    }
}
```

I.e., the getter returns a copy of the value from the internal array with `return _items[index];`. It is not an alias for the array index.

To avoid this kind of problem, structs should be immutable. Or use a class instead. Classes are reference types and class variables always contain a reference.

Comment: So I could store pointers to struct in my list instead of struct to use the list as I intended ?

Comment: If you want to do this, then you'd better create a class instead of a struct. Classes are reference types and class variables always contain a reference. To avoid this kind of problem, structs should be immutable.